# Use link tooltips in expanded user cards rather than link text

Tags: feature-request, user-card

The new expanded user card shows a list of links at the bottom of it which it gets from the profile text. However it uses what ever the link text is there, and cuts off it 15 characters and appends an elipse.

What would be nice is to use the link tooltip, if it is specified, here instead of the full link title as this would allow the profile author to provide a shorter text or text with more meaning at a glance. This would improve the readibility of the expanded card for authors who care enough.

Examples (using things in my profile):

- I have a link with the text "Microsoft Most Valuable Professional" which gets cut off and rightly so, it is too long. However it could be shorted to "MVP" using the tooltip for the expanded card.
- I have a link with the text "www.sadev.co.za" - however that means very little to anyone checking the expanded card. I would make more sense to them to see "Blog" which could be set with the tooltip.